# EOLESysError Bad Variable Type error on creating pdf files with OpenOffice

Tags: delphi, pdf, activex, openoffice.org

I was succcesfully using the technique discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819191/saving-to-pdf-from-openoffice) to create pdf files (from doc files) using Openoffice's ActiveX.

Recently, and using the smae OO version (3.3) the code doesn't work anymore, on this line (please refer to he code in the link above):

```
FilterParams[0] := CreateProperty('FilterName', AnsiString('writer_pdf_Export'));
```

I got EOLESysError "Bad Variable Type".

Could you give me an hand in solving the issue?

Comment: I just verified the code from my post linked in your question with current version OpenOffice.org 3.4.0 and it works fine for me. Could you include your current code ?

Comment: Which Delphi Version do you use?

Comment: I've just tried it with Delphi 2007. In Delphi XE2 I can see what you've described.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747427/excel-type-library-delphi-2009-bad-variable-type there is a problem with Variants

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747427/excel-type-library-delphi-2009-bad-variable-type) i solved the problem in this way:

```
function CreateProperty(const AName: AnsiString; const AValue: Variant): Variant;
  begin
    Result := StarOffice.Bridge_GetStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue');
    Result.Name := AName;
    Result.Value := AValue;
  end;
```

changed to

```
function CreateProperty(const AName: AnsiString; const AValue: Variant): Variant;
  var
    AVal : Variant;
  begin
    Result := StarOffice.Bridge_GetStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue');
    Result.Name := AName;
    AVal := AValue; // this is done to avoid 'Bad Variable Type'
    Result.Value := AVal;
  end;
```

You can resolve it also by removing `const` at the `AValue` parameter:

```
function CreateProperty(const AName: AnsiString; AValue: Variant): Variant;
begin
  Result := StarOffice.Bridge_GetStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue');
  Result.Name := AName;
  Result.Value := AValue;
end;
```

Comment: See another way to fix. I've updated also my post to the question you've linked in this question. It seems you can't pass string through constant variant parameter in Unicode versions of Delphi (?). I don't know much about variant types, so I can't unfortunately explain you what has changed and why this works in non Unicode versions of Delphi.